# SQLite no such table exception

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite

Hello and have a nice day,

I have an already populated database, I managed to fill a ListActivity with the values of a particular column but my problem is this: I want to have a menu item that says "Clear data" and by clicking it my(unique ) table in my database is dropped but all I get is

> 01-04 12:43:48.768: E/AndroidRuntime(18563): Caused by:
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: MAIN_TABLE
>   (code 1): , while compiling: select rowid _id,* from MAIN_TABLE

Any help would be much appreciated. I ll post some code. Ask for more if you need, thanks.

```
public class SavedProfilesSQLiteDb extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

static final String TAG="database";

static final int DATABASE_VERSION=1;
static final String DATABASE_NAME="savedProfilesDB.db";

public SavedProfilesSQLiteDb(Context context, String name,
        CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(Contract.Columns.CREATE_TABLE);
    Log.d(TAG, "Database created");

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    Log.d(TAG, "onUpgrade()");
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+ Contract.Columns.TABLE);
    onCreate(db);

}



static class Contract{
    private Contract(){};

    public static abstract class Columns implements BaseColumns{

    static final String _id="_id";
    static final String TABLE="MAIN_TABLE";
    static final String NAME="NAME_EMPTY";
    static final String PERSONAL_MESSAGE="PERSONAL_MESSAGE_EMPTY";
    static final String FACEBOOK_PAGE="FACEBOOK_PAGE_EMPTY";
    static final String E_MAIL="E_MAIL_EMPTY";
    static final String MOBILE="MOBILE_EMPTY";
    static final String ADDITIONAL_INFORMATION="ADDITIONAL_INFORMATION_EMPTY";

    static final String CREATE_TABLE="CREATE TABLE " + TABLE + "( "+_id+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
              + NAME + " TEXT,"
            + PERSONAL_MESSAGE + " TEXT," +FACEBOOK_PAGE+ " TEXT,"+E_MAIL+ " TEXT,"+MOBILE+ " TEXT,"+ADDITIONAL_INFORMATION+ ")";

    static final String ColumnsArray[] ={ NAME,PERSONAL_MESSAGE,FACEBOOK_PAGE,E_MAIL,MOBILE,ADDITIONAL_INFORMATION};
    }


}
```

}

and the drop table Sql statement:

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem){
        int itemId = menuItem.getItemId();
        if (itemId == R.id.Clearhistory) {
            String sql="DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+SavedProfilesSQLiteDb.Contract.Columns.TABLE;
            db.execSQL(sql);
            finish();
            startActivity(getIntent());
        }

            return true;

}
```

Don't be too harsh, still learning!!

Comment: You drop the table in your code and then get an exception saying it doesn't exists when doing a `select` - so the `drop` works and the snippet you posted doesn't include the part that causes the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
String sql = "DELETE FROM " + SavedProfilesSQLiteDb.Contract.Columns.TABLE;
```

Since you don't want to remove the table but just remove its contents.

Comment: That's not valid for sqlite.

Comment: @laalto thanks, corrected it. Somehow I thought I used `TRUNCATE` in android before but I was mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot drop table that does not exist, which is what you are doing. And for me "clear" should just delete all rows from the table, not dropping the table.

Comment: But the table does exist... That's how I query it in the first place to get the values of Name column. It's just that I haven't posted the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
static final String CREATE_TABLE="CREATE TABLE " + TABLE + "( "+_id+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
          + NAME + " TEXT,"
        + PERSONAL_MESSAGE + " TEXT," +FACEBOOK_PAGE+ " TEXT,"+E_MAIL+ " TEXT,"+MOBILE+ " TEXT,"+ADDITIONAL_INFORMATION+ ")"; is wrong.


ADDITIONAL_INFORMATION column dont have type. so table wont get created
```

one more issue

`while compiling: select rowid _id,* from MAIN_TABLE` this says while select statement error occurred not while dropping

Comment: This is not true, the `type-name` is not mandatory, see http://www.sqlite.org/syntaxdiagrams.html#column-def